# Excel VBA Mypresentation.ApplyTemplate with generic path file

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I want to use a template to copy data from EXCEL to a POWERPOINT presentation with EXCEL VBA. It works when I use an explicit path. However I want to use a relative path to run it, but its throw me the following error

```
Sub PowerPoint()

Dim rng As Excel.Range
Dim PowerPointApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim myPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim mySlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim myShapeRange As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim Template As String




'Copy Range from Excel
  Set rng = Worksheets("Contact Page").Range("C2:O38")


'Create an Instance of PowerPoint
  On Error Resume Next

    'Is PowerPoint already opened?
      Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

    'Clear the error between errors
      Err.Clear

    'If PowerPoint is not already open then open PowerPoint
      If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

    'Handle if the PowerPoint Application is not found
      If Err.Number = 429 Then
        MsgBox "PowerPoint could not be found, aborting."
        Exit Sub
      End If

  On Error GoTo 0

'Make PowerPoint Visible and Active
  PowerPointApp.Visible = True
  PowerPointApp.Activate

'Create a New Presentation

  Template = CurDir()
  Template = Template & "\TEMPLATE3.potm"
  Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add
   myPresentation.ApplyTemplate (Template)
  'myPresentation.ApplyTemplate ("C:\Users\Oriol\Documents\3mundi\Reporting\BR\New Model\TEMPLATE3.potm")
  myPresentation.PageSetup.SlideSize = ppSlideSizeOnScreen
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7lfZ.jpg)

What Should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the template file is in the same folder of the Excel file, change the statement:

```
Template = CurDir()
```

to:

```
Template = ThisWorkbook.Path
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the Excel file in the same locations as your potm? CurDir() returns the path that the excel file is currently saved in. So if your potm is saved in a subfolder, you will want to use that sub-folder in the path as well:

```
Template = CurDir()
Template = Template & "\SubFolder\TEMPLATE3.potm"
```